# App is crashing in Main Thread- EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL), Xcode crash report is redirecting to Firebase Library

Tags: firebase

Here is the crash log attached-

Incident Identifier: 64813956-C44C-44AD-9BAC-3202E2B917DF
Hardware Model:      iPhone14,2
Process:             __ [5030]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E2923602-E7D8-45CA-AC8F-81BBDAE2BBED/**.app/**
Identifier:         __
Version:             9.0.4 (8)
AppStoreTools:       13F100
AppVariant:          1:iPhone14,2:15
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Background
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           __[1191]

Date/Time:           2022-07-23 19:09:39.4396 +0530
Launch Time:         2022-07-23 18:00:47.6213 +0530
OS Version:          iPhone OS 15.6 (19G71)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    1.70.01
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: FRONTBOARD 2343432205
<RBSTerminateContext| domain:10 code:0x8BADF00D explanation:scene-update watchdog transgression: application<__>:5030 exhausted real (wall clock) time allowance of 10.00 seconds
ProcessVisibility: Background
ProcessState: Running
WatchdogEvent: scene-update
WatchdogVisibility: Background
WatchdogCPUStatistics: (
"Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 25.120 (user 20.330, system 4.790), 39% CPU",
"Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 10.751, 17% CPU"
) reportType:CrashLog maxTerminationResistance:Interactive>

Triggered by Thread:  0

Kernel Triage:
VM - Compressor failed a blocking pager_get
VM - Compressor failed a blocking pager_get

Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a2b370d0 CFCharacterSetIsCharacterMember + 8 (CFCharacterSet.c:1816)
1   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a2b58248 -[__NSCFCharacterSet characterIsMember:] + 20 (CFObject.m:1346)
2   Foundation                      0x00000001a4322170 _NSScanLongLongFromString + 876 (NSScanner.m:60)
3   __                          0x0000000105576264 +[FUtilities intForString:] + 128 (FUtilities.m:306)
4   __                          0x00000001055208b8 __30-[FChildrenNode valForExport:]_block_invoke + 264 (FChildrenNode.m:190)
5   __                          0x0000000105573010 __67-[FTreeSortedDictionary enumerateKeysAndObjectsReverse:usingBlock:]_block_invoke.58 + 40 (FTreeSortedDictionary.m:150)
6   __                          0x0000000105541960 -[FLLRBValueNode inorderTraversal:] + 176 (FLLRBValueNode.m:48)
7   __                          0x0000000105541908 -[FLLRBValueNode inorderTraversal:] + 88 (FLLRBValueNode.m:47)
8   __                          0x0000000105541994 -[FLLRBValueNode inorderTraversal:] + 228 (FLLRBValueNode.m:49)
9   __                          0x0000000105541908 -[FLLRBValueNode inorderTraversal:] + 88 (FLLRBValueNode.m:47)
10  __                          0x0000000105572f54 -[FTreeSortedDictionary enumerateKeysAndObjectsReverse:usingBlock:] + 316 (FTreeSortedDictionary.m:149)
11  __                          0x000000010552183c -[FChildrenNode enumerateChildrenUsingBlock:] + 80 (FChildrenNode.m:367)
12  __                          0x0000000105520514 -[FChildrenNode valForExport:] + 348 (FChildrenNode.m:174)
13  __                          0x00000001055207ec __30-[FChildrenNode valForExport:]_block_invoke + 60 (FChildrenNode.m:176)
14  __                          0x000000010551dc88 -[FArraySortedDictionary enumerateKeysAndObjectsReverse:usingBlock:] + 520 (FArraySortedDictionary.m:233)
15  __                          0x000000010552183c -[FChildrenNode enumerateChildrenUsingBlock:] + 80 (FChildrenNode.m:367)
16  __                          0x0000000105520514 -[FChildrenNode valForExport:] + 348 (FChildrenNode.m:174)
17  __                          0x00000001055207ec _*30-[FChildrenNode valForExport:]*block_invoke + 60 (FChildrenNode.m:176)
18  __                          0x000000010551dc88 -[FArraySortedDictionary enumerateKeysAndObjectsReverse:usingBlock:] + 520 (FArraySortedDictionary.m:233)
19  __                          0x000000010552183c -[FChildrenNode enumerateChildrenUsingBlock:] + 80 (FChildrenNode.m:367)
20  __                          0x0000000105520514 -[FChildrenNode valForExport:] + 348 (FChildrenNode.m:174)
21  __                          0x0000000105536a0c -[FIRDataSnapshot value] + 76 (FIRDataSnapshot.m:40)
22  __                          0x000000010534c980 closure #1 in PinDispatch.addObserverForRide(rideID:forNearby:) + 236 (PinDispatch.swift:1783)
23  __                          0x000000010528a6cc $s8__15FirebaseHandlerC015getResponseFromC09addedPath12onCompletionySS_ySo15FIRDataSnapshotCctFyAH_So7NSErrorCSgtcfU* + 4 (FirebaseHandler.swift:24)
24  __                          0x000000010528a6cc partial apply for closure #1 in FirebaseHandler.getResponseFromFirebase(addedPath:onCompletion:) + 20 (:0)
25  __                          0x000000010528b040 $s8__15FirebaseHandlerC04makeC19RequestWithObserver024_EDBAA01EC6873A021A9D1F2N7FDAE871LL5route12onCompletionySS_ySo15FIRDataSnapshotC_So7NSErrorCSgtctFyAIcfU* + 192 (FirebaseHandler.swift:0)
26  __                          0x000000010528b040 partial apply for closure #1 in FirebaseHandler.makeFirebaseRequestWithObserver(route:onCompletion:) + 232 (:0)
27  __                          0x000000010528a944 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@guaranteed FIRDataSnapshot) -> () + 52 (:0)
28  __                          0x00000001055789ac __43-[FValueEventRegistration fireEvent:queue:]_block_invoke.42 + 88 (FValueEventRegistration.m:81)
29  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a27f2e6c _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32 (init.c:1517)
30  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a27f4a30 _dispatch_client_callout + 20 (object.m:560)
31  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a2802f48 _dispatch_main_queue_drain + 928 (inline_internal.h:2622)
32  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a2802b98 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 44 (queue.c:7770)
33  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a2b45800 **CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE** + 16 (CFRunLoop.c:1795)
34  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a2aff704 __CFRunLoopRun + 2532 (CFRunLoop.c:3144)
35  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a2b12bc8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600 (CFRunLoop.c:3268)
36  GraphicsServices                0x00000001bec7d374 GSEventRunModal + 164 (GSEvent.c:2200)
37  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a5486b58 -[UIApplication _run] + 1100 (UIApplication.m:3511)
38  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a5208090 UIApplicationMain + 364 (UIApplication.m:5064)
39  __                          0x00000001050f7ea4 main + 68 (AppDelegate.swift:29)
40  dyld                            0x00000001071d9da4 start + 520 (dyldMain.cpp:879)

Thread 1 name:
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001da7824a0 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001da782ae4 mach_msg + 76 (mach_msg.c:119)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a2afad30 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 372 (CFRunLoop.c:2646)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a2aff1bc __CFRunLoopRun + 1180 (CFRunLoop.c:3000)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a2b12bc8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600 (CFRunLoop.c:3268)
5   Foundation                      0x00000001a4305444 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 236 (NSRunLoop.m:373)
6   Foundation                      0x00000001a4346e0c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 92 (NSRunLoop.m:420)
7   UIKitCore                       0x00000001a5400cc4 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 524 (UIEventFetcher.m:1167)
8   Foundation                      0x00000001a435541c **NSThread__start** + 808 (NSThread.m:972)
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002144f19ac _pthread_start + 148 (pthread.c:891)
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002144f0e68 thread_start + 8

Thread 2 name:
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001da7824a0 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001da782ae4 mach_msg + 76 (mach_msg.c:119)
2   __                          0x0000000105503cac FIRCLSMachExceptionReadMessage + 60 (FIRCLSMachException.c:192)
3   __                          0x0000000105503cac FIRCLSMachExceptionServer + 108 (FIRCLSMachException.c:168)
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002144f19ac _pthread_start + 148 (pthread.c:891)
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002144f0e68 thread_start + 8

Thread 3 name:
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001da7824a0 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001da782ae4 mach_msg + 76 (mach_msg.c:119)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a2afad30 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 372 (CFRunLoop.c:2646)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a2aff1bc __CFRunLoopRun + 1180 (CFRunLoop.c:3000)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a2b12bc8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600 (CFRunLoop.c:3268)
5   CFNetwork                       0x00000001a358f1dc +[__CFN_CoreSchedulingSetRunnable _run:] + 472 (CoreSchedulingSet.mm:1372)
6   Foundation                      0x00000001a435541c **NSThread__start** + 808 (NSThread.m:972)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002144f19ac _pthread_start + 148 (pthread.c:891)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002144f0e68 thread_start + 8

Thread 4 name:
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001da7824a0 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001da782ae4 mach_msg + 76 (mach_msg.c:119)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a2afad30 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 372 (CFRunLoop.c:2646)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a2aff1bc __CFRunLoopRun + 1180 (CFRunLoop.c:3000)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a2b12bc8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600 (CFRunLoop.c:3268)
5   Foundation                      0x00000001a4305444 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 236 (NSRunLoop.m:373)
6   __                          0x0000000105567254 -[_FSRRunLoopThread main] + 252 (FSRWebSocket.m:1860)
7   Foundation                      0x00000001a435541c **NSThread__start** + 808 (NSThread.m:972)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002144f19ac _pthread_start + 148 (pthread.c:891)
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002144f0e68 thread_start + 8

Thread 5 name:
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001da783164 select$DARWIN_EXTSN + 8
1   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a2b9eb68 __CFSocketManager + 644 (CFSocket.c:1343)
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002144f19ac _pthread_start + 148 (pthread.c:891)
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002144f0e68 thread_start + 8

Thread 6 name:
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001da7824a0 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001da782ae4 mach_msg + 76 (mach_msg.c:119)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a2afad30 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 372 (CFRunLoop.c:2646)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a2aff1bc __CFRunLoopRun + 1180 (CFRunLoop.c:3000)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a2b12bc8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600 (CFRunLoop.c:3268)
5   Foundation                      0x00000001a4305444 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 236 (NSRunLoop.m:373)
6   __                          0x0000000105aac8f4 -[GMSx_GTMSimpleWorkerThread main] + 184
7   Foundation                      0x00000001a435541c **NSThread__start** + 808 (NSThread.m:972)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002144f19ac _pthread_start + 148 (pthread.c:891)
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002144f0e68 thread_start + 8

Thread 7 name:
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001da7824a0 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001da782ae4 mach_msg + 76 (mach_msg.c:119)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a2afad30 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 372 (CFRunLoop.c:2646)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a2aff1bc __CFRunLoopRun + 1180 (CFRunLoop.c:3000)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a2b12bc8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600 (CFRunLoop.c:3268)
5   Foundation                      0x00000001a4305444 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 236 (NSRunLoop.m:373)
6   __                          0x0000000105aac8f4 -[GMSx_GTMSimpleWorkerThread main] + 184
7   Foundation                      0x00000001a435541c **NSThread__start** + 808 (NSThread.m:972)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002144f19ac _pthread_start + 148 (pthread.c:891)
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002144f0e68 thread_start + 8

Thread 8 name:
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001da7824a0 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001da782ae4 mach_msg + 76 (mach_msg.c:119)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a2afad30 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 372 (CFRunLoop.c:2646)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a2aff1bc __CFRunLoopRun + 1180 (CFRunLoop.c:3000)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a2b12bc8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600 (CFRunLoop.c:3268)
5   Foundation                      0x00000001a4305444 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 236 (NSRunLoop.m:373)
6   __                          0x0000000105aac8f4 -[GMSx_GTMSimpleWorkerThread main] + 184
7   Foundation                      0x00000001a435541c **NSThread__start** + 808 (NSThread.m:972)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002144f19ac _pthread_start + 148 (pthread.c:891)
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002144f0e68 thread_start + 8

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002144f0e54 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002144f0e54 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 11 name:
Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001da783138 __ulock_wait + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a27f5420 _dlock_wait + 56 (lock.c:326)
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a27f51d4 _dispatch_thread_event_wait_slow + 56 (lock.c:366)
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a2803f70 **DISPATCH_WAIT_FOR_QUEUE** + 356 (lock.h:330)
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a2803b28 _dispatch_sync_f_slow + 144 (queue.c:1774)
5   UIKitCore                       0x00000001a52e0a20 __37-[_UIRemoteKeyboards startConnection]_block_invoke_3 + 136 (*UIRemoteKeyboards.m:1094)
6   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a2b15b24 **invoking*** + 148
7   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a2b33610 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 468 (NSForwarding.m:3378)
8   Foundation                      0x00000001a4321918 **NSXPCCONNECTION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_REPLY_BLOCK** + 24 (NSXPCConnection.m:170)
9   Foundation                      0x00000001a4342f54 -[NSXPCConnection _decodeAndInvokeReplyBlockWithEvent:sequence:replyInfo:] + 572 (NSXPCConnection.m:316)
10  Foundation                      0x00000001a431d460 __88-[NSXPCConnection _sendInvocation:orArguments:count:methodSignature:selector:withProxy:]_block_invoke_3 + 212 (NSXPCConnection.m:1630)
11  libxpc.dylib                    0x00000002145266ac _xpc_connection_reply_callout + 124 (serializer.c:119)
12  libxpc.dylib                    0x0000000214519bcc _xpc_connection_call_reply_async + 88 (connection.c:833)
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a27f4ab0 _dispatch_client_callout3 + 20 (object.m:586)
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a2812214 _dispatch_mach_msg_async_reply_invoke + 340 (mach.c:2418)
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a27fc000 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 376 (inline_internal.h:0)
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a27fccb4 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 444 (queue.c:3944)
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a2807500 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 648 (queue.c:6732)
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002144f10bc _pthread_wqthread + 288 (pthread.c:2599)
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002144f0e5c start_wqthread + 8

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
x0: 0x00000002830fca50   x1: 0x0000000000000031   x2: 0x0000000000000031   x3: 0x0000000000000000
x4: 0x0000000000000000   x5: 0x0000000000000000   x6: 0x0000000000000031   x7: 0x0000000000000f00
x8: 0x0000000000000000   x9: 0x00000001ec9ec2db  x10: 0x0000000290851cd3  x11: 0x000f0002802f9800
x12: 0x000000000000000e  x13: 0x00000002802f9890  x14: 0x000000000aa00000  x15: 0x00000001fc344608
x16: 0x00000001fc344608  x17: 0x0347c001a2b58234  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0xa0c66d68ef888b31
x20: 0x0000000282bf9c80  x21: 0x0000000000000031  x22: 0x00000001ec9ec2db  x23: 0x0000000000000000
x24: 0x00000001fc352000  x25: 0x00000002832015c0  x26: 0x00000002833dfe70  x27: 0xa0ce65b2ba1911d1
x28: 0x00000001ec9ec000   fp: 0x000000016b0edcf0   lr: 0x4410a901a2b58248
sp: 0x000000016b0edcd0   pc: 0x00000001a2b370d0 cpsr: 0x60001000
esr: 0x92000007 (Data Abort) byte read Translation fault

Binary Images:
0x104d10000 - 0x106883fff __ arm64  <64c8b7b612c531b4b256bd66c20fdaf8> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E2923602-E7D8-45CA-AC8F-81BBDAE2BBED/**.app/**
0x1071c0000 - 0x107217fff dyld arm64e  <66e1fb2668f8379ba052eb8b8291b5e1> /usr/lib/dyld
0x1a27f1000 - 0x1a2836fff libdispatch.dylib arm64e   /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x1a2af4000 - 0x1a2f49fff CoreFoundation arm64e  <6b22dd8135853be6bc77ba19810ec0f2> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x1a3317000 - 0x1a37d8fff CFNetwork arm64e  <106410ffdd4f3527ad531980fe8b0ddd> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x1a42ec000 - 0x1a45f6fff Foundation arm64e   /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x1a4f72000 - 0x1a680ffff UIKitCore arm64e  <137a95aada6d332cbc01e13bb9b6e317> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore
0x1bec7c000 - 0x1bec84fff GraphicsServices arm64e   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x1da781000 - 0x1da7b6fff libsystem_kernel.dylib arm64e  <9ab02ad0348c30cb99f40979c2d47515> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x2144f0000 - 0x2144fbfff libsystem_pthread.dylib arm64e   /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
0x21450b000 - 0x214547fff libxpc.dylib arm64e   /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib

EOF